# How to convert xelement to a string in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq, xelement

I have an error like

> == cannot be applied to operands of type string and xelement

.Here I am comparing

```
item.Element("APINumber").Value == apiitem
```

which gives error. Can anyone help to correct this error by doing any conversion or something

```
var apilist = from first in txrrc
              join second in drill
              on first.Element("APINumber").Value 
              equals second.Element("APINumber").Value
                           select first;
IEnumerable<XElement> items = from item in xml2.Descendants()
                .Elements("DrillingPermit")
                where item.Element("APINumber").Value == apiitem                                                  
                select (XElement)item;
```

Comment: can you share your ``xml`` please? may be you need to use``apiitem.Element("APINumber").Value``

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here as I don't know the `apiitem` type though since `.Value` is string, then the type is `XElement`

```
item.Element("APINumber").Value == apiitem.Value
```